# How to calculate row means for sparse matrix with full zero rows?

Tags: r, matrix

I want to calculate the row means for a sparse matrix. Now it can happen, that some rows only contain zeros, so an example would look something like this:

```
3 x 3 sparse Matrix of class "dgCMatrix"
      
[1,] 1 . .
[2,] . 1 .
[3,] . . .
```

If I try to calculate the means using rowMeans(matrix), I get an error message:

> ```
> Error in rowMeans(matrix) : 'x' must be an array of at least two dimensions
> ```

I do not want to convert the matrix to the base R matrix, since they can get quite large.
Also I would like to avoid removing these full-zero rows, but maybe it is the only option.

Do you have some other ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It works with a reproducible example

```
library(Matrix)
m1 <- sparseMatrix(x = 1, i = 1:2, j = 1:2, dims = c(3, 3))
rowMeans(m1) 
[1] 0.3333333 0.3333333 0.0000000
```